# Dictionary keys and values to separate numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary as

```
Samples = {5.207403005022627: 0.69973543384229719, 6.8970222167794759: 0.080782939731898179, 7.8338517407140973: 0.10308033284258854, 8.5301143255505334: 0.018640838362318335, 10.418899728838058: 0.14427355015329846, 5.3983946820220501: 0.51319796560976771}
```

I want to separate the `keys` and `values` into 2 `numpy` arrays.
I tried `np.array(Samples.keys(),dtype=np.float)` but i get an error `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use `np.fromiter` to directly create `numpy` arrays from the dictionary key and values views:

In python 3:

```
keys = np.fromiter(Samples.keys(), dtype=float)
vals = np.fromiter(Samples.values(), dtype=float)
```

In python 2:

```
keys = np.fromiter(Samples.iterkeys(), dtype=float)
vals = np.fromiter(Samples.itervalues(), dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 26):

On python 3.4, the following simply works:

```
Samples = {5.207403005022627: 0.69973543384229719, 6.8970222167794759: 0.080782939731898179, 7.8338517407140973: 0.10308033284258854, 8.5301143255505334: 0.018640838362318335, 10.418899728838058: 0.14427355015329846, 5.3983946820220501: 0.51319796560976771}

keys = np.array(list(Samples.keys()))
values = np.array(list(Samples.values()))
```

The reason `np.array(Samples.values())` doesn't give what you expect in Python 3 is that in Python 3, the values() method of a dict returns an iterable view, whereas in Python 2, it returns an actual list of the keys.

`keys = np.array(list(Samples.keys()))` will actually work in Python 2.7 as well, and will make your code more version agnostic. But the extra call to `list()` will slow it down marginally.

Comment: list() may not be the good option as it may suffle the values as the index of data is quite important.

Answer (score 6):

**In Python 3.7:**

```
import numpy as np

Samples = {5.207403005022627: 0.69973543384229719, 6.8970222167794759: 0.080782939731898179, 7.8338517407140973: 0.10308033284258854, 8.5301143255505334: 0.018640838362318335, 10.418899728838058: 0.14427355015329846, 5.3983946820220501: 0.51319796560976771}

keys = np.array(list(Samples.keys()))
vals = np.array(list(Samples.values()))
```

Note: It's important to say that in this Python version `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` return objects of type `dict_keys` and `dict_values`, respectively.

Answer (score 5):

If you care about **speed** (Python 3.7)

```py
rnd = np.random.RandomState(10)

for i in [10,100,1000,10000,100000]:
    test_dict = {j:j for j in rnd.uniform(-100,100,i)}
    assert len(test_dict) == i
    print(f"\nFor {i} keys\n-----------")
    
    %timeit keys = np.fromiter(test_dict.keys(), dtype=float)
    
    %timeit keys = np.array(list(test_dict.keys()))
```

**np.fromiter is 5-7 times faster**

```sh
For 10 keys
-----------
712 ns ± 4.77 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
1.65 µs ± 9.15 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

For 100 keys
-----------
1.87 µs ± 13.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
8.02 µs ± 22.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

For 1000 keys
-----------
13.7 µs ± 27.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
70.5 µs ± 251 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

For 10000 keys
-----------
128 µs ± 70.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
698 µs ± 455 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

For 100000 keys
-----------
1.45 ms ± 374 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
7.14 ms ± 6.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign all of the values to a list, and then convert to a `np.array()`.

```
import numpy as np

Samples = {5.207403005022627: 0.69973543384229719, 6.8970222167794759: 0.080782939731898179, 7.8338517407140973: 0.10308033284258854, 8.5301143255505334: 0.018640838362318335, 10.418899728838058: 0.14427355015329846, 5.3983946820220501: 0.51319796560976771}

keys = np.array(Samples.keys())
vals = np.array(Samples.values())
```

Or, if [you want to iterate over it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/36358823?noredirect=1):

```
import numpy as np

Samples = {5.207403005022627: 0.69973543384229719, 6.8970222167794759: 0.080782939731898179, 7.8338517407140973: 0.10308033284258854, 8.5301143255505334: 0.018640838362318335, 10.418899728838058: 0.14427355015329846, 5.3983946820220501: 0.51319796560976771}

keys = vals = []

for k, v in Samples.items():
    keys.append(k)
    vals.append(v)

keys = np.array(keys)
vals = np.array(vals)
```

Comment: Could u iterate over this array?

Comment: Do you want to iterate over it? If so, then yes.

Comment: When u do keys = np.array(Samples.keys()), could u iterate?

Answer (score -1):

```
keys = np.array(dictionary.keys())
values = np.array(dictionary.values())
```

Comment: No it won't work (at least in python 3.4):

>> np.array(Samples.keys())
Out[15]: array(dict_keys([5.207403005022627, 6.897022216779476, 7.833851740714097, 8.530114325550533, 10.418899728838058, 5.39839468202205]), dtype=object)

Which is not what you want!